# How to convert this nested JSON into an Excel or CSV file using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, export-to-csv

So I have this nested json and I'm struggling with the conversion into a tabular form because of how it's shaped, it could become a .xslx or .csv.

I tried doing it like this but I didn't work.

```
# Load the JSON data into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_json(response_data, typ='series')

# Convert the DataFrame to a flattened dictionary
flat_dict = pd.json_normalize(df.to_dict())

# Export the flattened dictionary to an Excel file
flat_dict.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

The json:

```
{
    "A": [
        {
            "Price": 200,
            "category": 620,
            "service": {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "KAL",
                "description": "Description",
                "Validity": null,
                "order": 0,
                "services": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "financeable": true,
                        "benefit": {
                            "id": 235,
                            "name": "ZSX",
                            "Priced": null
                        },
                        "Execution": null,
                        "serviceId": 112,
                        "label": "Colab"
                    }
                ],
                "selection": false
            },
            "creditTO": {
                "id": 0,
                "duration": 6,
                "Type": "standard",
                "Tax": 51,
                "total": 400,
                "promotion": false
            }
        }
    ],
        "B": [
        {
            "Price": 200,
            "category": 620,
            "service": {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "BTX",
                "description": "Description",
                "Validity": null,
                "order": 0,
                "services": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "financeable": true,
                        "benefit": {
                            "id": 235,
                            "name": "ZSX",
                            "Priced": null
                        },
                        "Execution": null,
                        "serviceId": 112,
                        "label": "Colab"
                    }
                ],
                "selection": false
            },
            "creditTO": {
                "id": 0,
                "duration": 9,
                "Type": "standard",
                "Tax": 51,
                "total": 400,
                "promotion": false
            }
        }
    ],
        "C": [
        {
            "Price": 600,
            "category": 620,
            "service": {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "FLS",
                "description": "Description",
                "Validity": null,
                "order": 0,
                "services": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "financeable": true,
                        "benefit": {
                            "id": 235,
                            "name": "ZSX",
                            "Priced": null
                        },
                        "Execution": null,
                        "serviceId": 112,
                        "label": "Colab"
                    }
                ],
                "selection": false
            },
            "creditTO": {
                "id": 0,
                "duration": 12,
                "Type": "standard",
                "Tax": 51,
                "total": 400,
                "promotion": false
            }
        }
    ],
        "D": [
        {
            "Price": 705,
            "category": 620,
            "service": {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "TRW",
                "description": "Description",
                "Validity": null,
                "order": 0,
                "services": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "financeable": true,
                        "benefit": {
                            "id": 235,
                            "name": "ZSX",
                            "Priced": null
                        },
                        "Execution": null,
                        "serviceId": 112,
                        "label": "Colab"
                    }
                ],
                "selection": false
            },
            "creditTO": {
                "id": 0,
                "duration": 18,
                "Type": "standard",
                "Tax": 67,
                "total": 245,
                "promotion": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Ideally, the output should look like this:

[image]

Any suggestion on how to transform it using Python ? Could be pandas or any other module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding to what Corralien wrote, try something like this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = json.loads(response_json)
df = pd.concat({k: pd.json_normalize(v) for k, v in data.items()}).droplevel(1)

df = pd.concat((df, pd.concat({k: pd.json_normalize(v) for k, v in df['service.services'].items()}).droplevel(1).add_prefix('service.')), axis=1).drop(columns='service.services')
```

This works under the assumption you will always have a list under the `service.services` column.

Output:

```
|    |   Price |   category |   service.id | service.name   | service.description   | service.Validity   |   service.order | service.selection   |   creditTO.id |   creditTO.duration | creditTO.Type   |   creditTO.Tax |   creditTO.total | creditTO.promotion   |   service.id | service.financeable   | service.Execution   |   service.serviceId | service.label   |   service.benefit.id | service.benefit.name   | service.benefit.Priced   |
|:---|--------:|-----------:|-------------:|:---------------|:----------------------|:-------------------|----------------:|:--------------------|--------------:|--------------------:|:----------------|---------------:|-----------------:|:---------------------|-------------:|:----------------------|:--------------------|--------------------:|:----------------|---------------------:|:-----------------------|:-------------------------|
| A  |     200 |        620 |           15 | KAL            | Description           |                    |               0 | False               |             0 |                   6 | standard        |             51 |              400 | False                |          100 | True                  |                     |                 112 | Colab           |                  235 | ZSX                    |                          |
| B  |     200 |        620 |           15 | BTX            | Description           |                    |               0 | False               |             0 |                   9 | standard        |             51 |              400 | False                |          100 | True                  |                     |                 112 | Colab           |                  235 | ZSX                    |                          |
| C  |     600 |        620 |           15 | FLS            | Description           |                    |               0 | False               |             0 |                  12 | standard        |             51 |              400 | False                |          100 | True                  |                     |                 112 | Colab           |                  235 | ZSX                    |                          |
| D  |     705 |        620 |           15 | TRW            | Description           |                    |               0 | False               |             0 |                  18 | standard        |             67 |              245 | False                |          100 | True                  |                     |                 112 | Colab           |                  235 | ZSX                    |                          |
```

Comment: This works perfectly! The output is exactly how I need, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on first level records to create individual dataframes then concatenate them to get the expected output:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = json.loads(response_json)
df = pd.concat({k: pd.json_normalize(v) for k, v in data.items()}).droplevel(1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Price  category  service.id service.name service.description  ... creditTO.duration  creditTO.Type creditTO.Tax  creditTO.total  creditTO.promotion
A    200       620          15          KAL         Description  ...                 6       standard           51             400               False
B    200       620          15          BTX         Description  ...                 9       standard           51             400               False
C    600       620          15          FLS         Description  ...                12       standard           51             400               False
D    705       620          15          TRW         Description  ...                18       standard           67             245               False
```

Comment: That's not enough, as there are deeper nested lists inside. `service.services` end up as a list in a cell.